# API for adding response into review on App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I see in documentation https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/betaAppReviewDetails, an API able to retrieve reviews in app store.

My question:is there any API to reply the custom review in App Store?(similar with  Google Play Store API: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews)

Thanks you so much for you replies

Answer (score 0):

Beta App Review Details is the API you use to provide details to App Review. See [the documentation for this API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/testflight/beta_app_review_detail). It is unrelated to customer reviews on the App Store.

At this time there is no public API to respond to customer reviews.

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply, you mentionned "no public API", does private API exist for those actions ?

Answer (score 0):

There is itunes api to get reviews  [https://itunes.apple.com/{country-code}/rss/customerreviews/id={app-id}/xml](https://itunes.apple.com/%7Bcountry-code%7D/rss/customerreviews/id=%7Bapp-id%7D/xml)

where country code is 2 letter code e.g. us (for USA) and app id is your apple app id from app store connect.

I am also looking for similar feature but there is no apple supported api to respond to reviews.